# I was looking to see if someone could tell me how secure this is

Tags: mysql

I am writing a code that will check 2 different tables to determine the privileges the user will have. The code looks like this:

```
    $query1 = ("SELECT 1 FROM `customers` WHERE `Email` = '$email' AND `Password` = '$password'");
    $query2 = ("SELECT 1 FROM `admins` WHERE `Email` = '$email' AND `Password` = '$password'");

    $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result1) == 1) {
        // Log user in as a Customer
        exit;
    } else if (mysql_num_rows($result2) == 1) {
        // Log user in as an Admin.
        exit;
    } else {
        // Direct user to registration page.
    }
```

Can anyone look at this and tell me if there would be any security risk by doing it this way? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is insecure  if for example my password was

```
OR 1=1
```

I get access. Use mysql prepared statements

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM customers WHERE Email = (?) AND Password = (?)"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have a change that your code is only known by you.

Secondly you have to check the input data. email and password area is not safety. You should prevent SQL injection. Otherwise your code is not secure.

By the way i'm offering you IP restricted login for admins. I'm using this. And it is more secure.

Answer (score 0):

One big problem here is that the code is vulnerable for sql injections.
Which basicly means that the user could put code in the email or password form to bypass the check you have here.

A start would be to perform the following to your input BEFORE you use them in your query:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

Though, the mysql library is not recommended by php, rather read about prepared statements in pdo here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

But you can try the mysql_real_escape_string to have a first security measure against sql injections.

Comment: How will `mysql_real_escape_string` help if my password is ` OR 1=1`

Comment: It will escape the ' character (\') so it will be seen as character rather than affecting the string. So the password will be \' OR 1=1\' which will not affect the query

Comment: That was formatting for stackoverflow - dont know why it appeared